# GameMaker Android project crashes on IAP

Tags: game-maker, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to implement a simple IAP in my GameMaker project for Android.
The "store" is a simple room with a button, with this code linked to the "Left mouse button released" event:

```
if iap_status() == iap_status_available
{
    var product = "donation";
    if ds_map_find_value(global.purchaseMap, product) == 0
    {
        iap_acquire(product, "");
    }
}
else
{
   show_message_async("Store is not available.");
}
```

and another object with this code linked to the "IAP" event:

```
var val = ds_map_find_value(iap_data, "type");

switch (val)
{
    case iap_ev_purchase:
        var map = ds_map_create();
        var purchase_id = ds_map_find_value(iap_data, "index");
        iap_purchase_details(purchase_id, map);
        if ds_map_find_value(map, "status") == iap_purchased
        {
            var product_id = ds_map_find_value(map, "product");
            ds_map_replace(global.purchaseMap, product_id, 1);
            switch(product_id)
            {
                case "donation":
                    iap_consume(product_id);
                break;
            }
        }
        ds_map_destroy(map);
    break;

    case iap_ev_consume:
        var product_id = ds_map_find_value(iap_data, "product");
        if ds_map_find_value(iap_data, "consumed")
        {
            ds_map_replace(global.purchaseMap, product_id, 0);

        }
    break;
}

ds_map_secure_save(global.purchaseMap, "iap_data.json");
```

The IAP is correctly called when the button is pressed, but when the transaction is completed, the game crashes and then crashes at every launch. If I cancel the transaction it doesn't crashes, so I was suspecting the `case iap_ev_consume:` part to be at fault.

I followed this tutorial: https://help.yoyogames.com/hc/en-us/articles/216755198-In-App-Purchases-Example

Why does my game crashes when an IAP is performed?

Comment: What version of GM:S are you currently using? There may be a known bug concerning IAP functions. Also, what's the app store you are developing IAP for? Google Play and Apple Store require slight different settings for purchases to work correctly.

Comment: `1.4.1763`, and I'm on Google Play.